# How to integrate just geographic locations from google adword api?

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I'm trying to integrate Google Adwords just geographic locations for one of my project.

Here I'm trying to get a list of available location for Adwords.

I try to search on google but no proper example.
please provide any reference or demo of this using API.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a list of all available geo targets from:

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/geotargeting